# Upgrade python3 pandas to newest version

Tags: 16.04, python3

I installed python3-pandas with

```
    sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

but I only got version 0.13. 
I googled a bit and found out that I need to install the .whl with

```
    pip3  install filename.whl
```

and that I need to be careful that the "c" is followed by my python version. I am currently running python 3.4.3 and I downloaded the

```
    pandas-0.19.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

I removed pandas with

```
    sudo apt-get remove python3-pandas
```

and tried

```
    pip3 install pandas-0.19.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

while being in the right directory (my download directory).
But I only got the error

```
    pandas-0.19.1-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

    Storing debug log for failure in /home/praktikant/.pip/pip.log
```

I really don't understand what went wrong.

Comment: Did you read the log? Is there some reason you must run a new version of pandas on Ubuntu 14.04 instead of 16.04 or 16.10?

Comment: The log says the same thing:  that it is not supported on this platform. I do have 16.04, why 14.04?

Comment: 'Not supported on this platform' seems clear enough. The package said 'No'. What's your question?